# trying to use the preservePath method in the Node.js express Multer API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to use multer to upload a file. There is a boolean preservePath method, but the the API is vague on how to implement. I need to extract the original absolute file path from the file to be uploaded for use in a workflow pipeline on a closed network.

My understanding is that the optional methods are setup in the variable assignment.
Here is what I think is the relevant storage definition:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + 
    path.extname(file.originalname));
    console.log(file);
  }
});
const upload = multer({
```

//*********************************
      preservePath: true,
//*********************************
      storage: storage,
    }).single('myImage');

Also, any guidance/input on how to construct clearer questions and clarifications would also be helpful.

Comment: Please share what (code) you have tried so far, or at least more example/details on the approach you are using.

Comment: I edited my initial question yesterday, so you might not have recieved a prompt, but I hop this offers to my clarity to my issue